# Install Git on CentOS 7 LEMP stack

Tags: linux, git, nginx, centos7

After about 6+ days and numerous rounds of spin-up/destroy I have FINALLY gotten my Digital Ocean droplet server up and running (ie I can view a live page of content at my ip).

At this point I am trying to install Git, and have installed/removed it 3 times so far as I keep getting 'close' to completion but then run into some error I can't find an answer for.  I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what my latest problem is so I can move forward with the actual development of my site rathe than spending over a week on the server build.

I have attempted to install version 2.6.2 of git on my server and have had to compile from source (something I am no where near familiar with).  I 'thought' I had it correct this time, but received the following error when I attempted to set my git user name:

## gitconfig --global user.name "MyUserName" (<--- last command I made)

## bash: gitconfig: command not found (<-- error i received)

I thought it was an issue with being in the wrong directory to run the command, so i ran which git and received the following output:

/usr/local/git/bin/git

This seems to be a binary (?) file and none of the directories listed in that path allow me to use gitconfig command either.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?  Do I need to remove (again!) and re-compile.  I don't desire to be a server admin, but really had thought (hoped?) spinning my own LEMP server on CentOS 7 would be simple - doing so on CentOS 6.* was.

Thanks for your help/advice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the packages in EPEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gitconfig isn't a command.

You'd do:

```
git config --global user.name "MyUserName"
```

Also you're really better off installing git via yum, rather than compiling from source unless there's a good reason to compile it yourself.

(Edit - updated answer with tested solution on Centos 7).

Comment: @palfrey thanks mike, i'll try this.  Re: installing from yum: yum doesnt give me the latest version - unless i did something wrong when yum installing....ran this in dir git-2.6.2 and received this error: error: invalid key: user.name=[MyUserName] (where [MyUserName] was my actual user name)...what did i do wrong?

Comment: sudo git config --global user.name="UserName"

error: invalid key: user.name=UserName

(where UserName is my actual username of course)

Comment: Try the updated solution above. I've tested it and it works for me on Centos 7.